# Как автоматизировать получение Wildcard-сертификатов?

Tags: nginx, ssl, dns, letsencrypt

Как автоматизировать получение Wildcard-сертификатов?

Сейчас практикую получение через Certbot/acme.sh, но везде нужно ждать, пока обновится DNS, не закрывая командную строку. В промышленных масштабах это очень долго. Подскажите, в какую сторону искать информацию.

Comment: Если честно, удивляет сама постановка вопроса - wildcard-ы как раз придуманы для того, чтобы упростить получение индивидуальных сертификатов. По идее, вы должны получать ровно один сертификат на домен. О каких промышленных масштабах может идти речь? В любом случае, подтверждение через DNS никуда не денется, и будет занимать время. Если вам не хочется сидеть перед консолью, запустите через GNU Screen - эта утилита запускает приложения в псевдотерминале, и сохраняет терминал, даже если закрыть screen.